# Joining 3 tables in SQL and displaying columns from each

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables that all share a common ID and I wish to display columns from each of these tables by joining based on this common ID.

I am able to join two of the three tables but when I include the third I get errors.

This is my script:

```
select TableA.CommonID, TableA.Column1, TableB.Column2, TableC.Column3
from TableA
join TableB on TableA.CommonID = TableB.CommonID
join TableC on TableA.CommonID = TableC.CommonID;
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: The first thing you are doing wrong is not posting the error. Not posting the error usually means you have not tried to understand it in the first place

Comment: you write right query .what is error? please mention

Comment: Either Column3 does not exist in TableC or CommonID does not exist in TableC. Please check that the names  TableC.Column3 and TableC.CommonID are written correctly including the right case

Comment: Sorry people it was incorrect syntax and I've fixed it...

Answer (score 0):

Try use InnerJoin to satisfy your requirement

```
SELECT a.CommonID, a.Column1, b.Column2, c.Column3
FROM TableA AS a
INNER JOIN TableB AS b ON a.CommonID = b.CommonID
INNER JOIN TableC AS c ON a.CommonID = c.CommonID
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no error by using MySQL.
Please see my test [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28b592/1)
As per comment it is necessary more details on DBMS and error you get.